# JavaScript: res.sendFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sendfile

I'm not sure why I am getting this error. Here is my code. 
Express was already installed with npm install express --save

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path');

app.get('/register.html',function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/register.html'));
});

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server is listening...")
})
```

Comment: Whats your Express version ? it should be greater than 4.8

Comment: Which version of Express are you using? (`npm ls express`)

Comment: 3.21.2  that could be the issue.

Comment: @AhmedAhmed sendFile supports from 4.8.0 or above see this https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1091

Comment: @VinodLouis Thanks, oul post back when I have updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update express to 4.8+

> npm update express --save